# Is there a Javascript implementation of the CryptoNight algorithm?

Tags: cryptonote, cryptonight, javascript, algorithm

Before I seek to write one of my own, I wanted to see if there's a CryptoNight Javascript algorithm anywhere out there.  I found the CryptoNoter project, but it only contains an obfuscated binary file taht does the heavy lifting, which is banned from most browsers anyway -- https://github.com/cryptonoter/CryptoNoter/issues/34 .  It would be nice if there were a JS implementation so that I could see the algorithm in action and play around with it on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is.

Do a `npm search cryptonight-hashing` and take a pick :)

```
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORD
cryptonight-hashing       | node-cryptonight-ha… | =moneroocean    | 2018-10-04 | 3.0.5    | crypton
node-cryptonight-lite     | node bindings for…   | =excitableaard… | 2018-02-01 | 1.0.1    | crypton
node-cryptonight          | node bindings for…   | =excitableaard… | 2018-10-08 | 1.2.0    | crypton
node-cryptonight-old-hard | node bindings for…   | =adaxi          | 2018-10-14 | 1.1.0    | cryptonware                      |                      |                 |            |          |        
turtlecoin-multi-hashing  | ![image](https://us… | =brandonlehmann | 2018-12-11 | 0.0.18   | scrypt
multi-hashing-bbscoin     | multi-hashing-bbsco… | =randing89      | 2018-09-23 | 1.0.2    | scrypt 
cryptonight-hash          | JavaScript…          | =andrehrf       | 2018-03-30 | 0.0.4    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course there is! As Cryptonight only uses *CPU* power and JavaScript is *client side* there are some:

-> Embed **CryptoNight speed test** (displays your **hashrate** etc.) : **https://myseries.lima-city.de/code/miner.html**

If you want to have your **own miner** (e.g for your website):

-> **https://coinhive.com/** (registration needed)

Answer (score 0):

BTW: If you want to mine via website, search no more --> [Tralex Web Miner](http://webminer.tralex.co)

Comment: **One** more [search on github](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=webminer&s=updated&type=Repositories) can't hurt.